# Embedded UIVIewController unexpectedly expands horizontally on touch or scroll

Tags: ios, xamarin

I have a UIViewController that has a UIScrollView. The scroll view embeds six different view controllers in UIViews via embed segues. The sixth embedded view controller expands horizontally on both scroll and touch...

This is not expected behavior. I'm not sure how I would do this even if I wanted to. What could be the culprit?

[image]

**Main VC:**

[image]

**Main VC Structure:**
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you gave the containerViews a static width of 320 , that's why the content doesn't fit for all devices , so the scrolling happens , you need to ctrl drag from the containerView to the main outerView and select **EqualWidths**

the known behavior is to have a contentView as the 1 child of the scrollview and hook it's width to the main outer view , instead of doing this with all subviews of the stackView like

```
> scrollView
 > contentView
   > containerView1
   > containerView2
```

then hooking the leading && trailing is enough to make it fill the current space plus it's positioning